# Date yyyy-mm format to integer

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need to take a current month, subtract one month, than convert it to format yyyy-mm and convert it to integer. Then assign it to a variable for next comparison in the where clause.

So the logic for that would be like

1. Today is 20.03.2019 (or whatever day and month it is)
2. After subtraction is 01.02.2019
3. After conversion to YYYY-MM format it's 201902
4. After conversion to integer it's 201902 integer

Could you please help me with a SQL approach in Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the expression:

```
to_number(to_char(trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'MM'), 'YYYYMM'))
```

The `add_months(sysdate, -1)` gives you today's date one month ago.

The `trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'MM')` gives you the first day of that month, via the `MM` argument to `trunc()`.

The `to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'MM') - interval '1' month, 'YYYYMM')` converts that to a string as `'201902'`.

Finally `to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'MM') - interval '1' month, 'YYYYMM'))` converts that string to a number.

The truncate step isn't really necessary as you're ignoring the day part anyway, but I've left it in to match the value shown in your second step.

You could also do `trunc(sysdate, 'MM') - interval '1' month` - subtract the interval *after* truncating the current month to its first day. The other way around, or without truncating, you might get a date error, e.g. if running on July 31st - as there is no June 31st.

Examples:

```
select to_number(to_char(trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'MM'), 'YYYYMM')) from dual;

TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'MM'),'YYYYMM'))
---------------------------------------------------------------
                                                         201902

select to_number(to_char(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'YYYYMM')) from dual;

TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'YYYYMM'))
---------------------------------------------------
                                             201902

select to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'MM') - interval '1' month, 'YYYYMM')) from dual;

TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')-INTERVAL'1'MONTH,'YYYYMM'))
-----------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           201902
```

> Then assign it to a variable for next comparison in the where clause.

You can use that expression directly in a `where` clause. If you're including it in the select list you can give it a column alias; but you can't refer to that alias in the `where` clause in the same level of query. You would need to use a subquery (inline view) or CTE - or just repeat the full expression.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this would be of any use to you, but here is some implementation:

1. Take the current date;
2. You could use the `ADD_MONTHS()` function to get the previous month;
3. I see that you are truncating the date so I also did that with the `TRUNC(,'MM')`;
4. Convert it to the format you mentioned;
5. Convert it to a number;

`SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1),'MM'),'YYYYMM')) FROM DUAL;`

Answer (score 0):

`Add_months` would subtract from your date which you then format as needed and cast to char and to number.

```
select to_number(to_char(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'YYYYMM')) from dual
```